# Declare enum Router Alamofire swift 2.0

Tags: swift, enums, alamofire

I'm trying to follow one example from Matt but i'm facing some strange thing.
I created one file named Router.swift and paste the following code:

```
//
//  Router.swift

import Alamofire

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
static let baseURLString = "http://example.com"

case CreateUser([String: AnyObject])
case ReadUser(String)
case UpdateUser(String, [String: AnyObject])
case DestroyUser(String)

var method: Alamofire.Method {
    switch self {
    case .CreateUser:
        return .POST
    case .ReadUser:
        return .GET
    case .UpdateUser:
        return .PUT
    case .DestroyUser:
        return .DELETE
    }
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .CreateUser:
        return "/users"
    case .ReadUser(let username):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    case .UpdateUser(let username, _):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    case .DestroyUser(let username):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    }
}
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Type 'Router' does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'
```

I'm using Alamofire branch swift-2.0 
Xcode 7R6

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a

```
  var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {...}
```

to the enum, which generates & returns the `NSURLRequest` from your other components like `path` or `method`

EXAMPLE:

```
var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {

    let URL = NSURL(string: baseURLString)!
    let mutableURLRequest = path != nil ? NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path!)) : NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
    if let authorizationHeader = authorizationHeader { mutableURLRequest.setValue(authorizationHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") }
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

    return encoding.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: [ "foo": "bar" ]).0

}
```

Comment: Btw, this isn't Swift 2, but I guess it should be the same

Comment: Getting the same error in the same line: enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

Comment: The `URLRequestConvertible` protocol definition is `public protocol URLRequestConvertible { var URLRequest: NSURLRequest { get }}` means the only property you need to implement is `var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {}` if you added this property you shouldn't get the same error, that's odd

Comment: Using this example, which implements same property as you mentioned, gave me same error. http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial

Comment: I didn't mean you should just copy-paste the example I wrote, what I meant was that the first obvious issue with your code is not having `URLRequest`, there might be other issues as well. if you follow the tutorial, under "Creating a Request Router" you can see that guy also has a `URLRequest` in his router

Comment: I understood what you meant. Couldn't make it works yet, but at least I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

From Alamofire's documentation, the URLRequest must be `NSMutableURLRequest` and not `NSURLRequest`.

So, have in the example above change to the following:

```
var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

    let URL = NSURL(string: baseURLString)!
    let mutableURLRequest = path != nil ? NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path!)) : NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
    if let authorizationHeader = authorizationHeader { mutableURLRequest.setValue(authorizationHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") }
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

    return encoding.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: [ "foo": "bar" ]).0

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your enum adopts URLRequestConvertible protocol, it must have a variable of type NSURLRequest named URLRequest.

And in Swift 1.2 This Works for me by conforming to NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible{

static let baseURLString = ""
static let clientId = ""
static let clientSecret = ""

case NewUser(String, String, String)

var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .NewUser:
            return "/users"
        }
    }

    var parameters: [String: AnyObject] {
        switch self {
        case .NewUser (let userName, let email, let password):
            let params = ["Username": userName, "Email": "\(email)", "Password": password, "Client_Id": Router.clientId,  "Client_Secret": Router.clientSecret]
            return params
        }
    }

    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
    let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

    return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
}

}
```